# How to find marginal MLE of multivariate normal covariance parameters without having mean?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, gaussian-process

I am trying to use Gaussian process regression to build an emulator for some computationally expensive computer code. I have a vector $y$ of 50 noiseless data points from the expensive code I am emulating, collected at points $x\in \mathbb R^3$. So I want $$y | \mu \sim N(\mu, R)$$ where $R$ is the covariance matrix for the points $x$, and $R_{i,j}$ is given by $$R_{i,j}=\prod_{k=1}^3 \rho_k ^{(x_{i,k}-x_{j,k})^2}$$ with $\rho_k\in(0,1)\ \forall k$.

In setting up my emulator, I intend to plug in the marginal MLEs of $\rho$. However, I have placed an improper uniform prior on $\mu$. Since I'm not estimating $\mu$ by its MLE, how do I find the marginal MLEs of $\rho$?

My question may be confused, because I myself am confused while asking it. If I appear to be too fundamentally confused to get a straightforward answer to what I'm trying to ask, then I would appreciate any attempts to clarify the situation or point out where I'm not making sense.

Comment: Why would your covariance matrix be a function of the data points?  More so, why would you even have a covariance matrix for $x$ in your model?  If you want $y$ to be a function of $x$, then each observation $y_i$ would seem to be a fuction of $x_{i,1}, \dots, x_{i,3}$ regardless of the values of $x_{j,\cdot}$ corresponding to other observations.

Comment: The data is modeled as a Gaussian process in which the correlation between the response at points $x_1,x_2$ depends upon the distance between $x_1$ and $x_2$. That is why the covariance matrix of the observations $y$ is a function of the locations, $x$, at which the observations are made.